# 10916 iisutil!ReadMultiStringParameterValueFromAnyService [helpfunc.cxx @ 490]:Inetinfo: Failed reading registry value

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I got this error when I run **vs2017 enterprise** .

```
iisutil!ReadMultiStringParameterValueFromAnyService [helpfunc.cxx @ 490]:Inetinfo: Failed reading registry value 
    Error(80070002): The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I googled for this error.but I find nothing to resolve my problem.

If I run the published project from is it's ok.but in visual studio, it has problem.

- remove .vs folder from solution,and run vs as administrator ,then change  port number in vs nothing happend.

  -remove and reinstall IIS and VisualStudio
  ,nothing happened to solve my problem.

plz Help me.
Tnx..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpret this crash dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158719/how-to-interpret-this-crash-dump)

Comment: i dont't know my problem is this post or not.the project worked correctly yesterday,but today ,it has problem.  anyway i could't find where stackoverflowException happend.

Comment: Finally i find the problem. the Native Code box was ticked in the Debuggers section of the Web section in Project Properties.

I don't know how this happened, I never ticked it.